# How to Convert stdClass object to int in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api

I want to search into my database with user_id and get the amount value(int type)

```
$user = (int)(request('user'));
    $money = (int)(request('money'));
    $data = (DB::select("select amount from user_check where user_id = '$user'"));
    $array = json_decode(json_encode($data), True);
    foreach ($data as $value) 
    {
        $array[] = $value->amount;
    } 
    if($array[0]>$money)
    {
        return response(['user ok'=>$array[0],'money'=>$money]);
    }
    else
    {
        //return response(['user'=>$user,'Not enough money'=>$data]);
        return response('user not ok');
    }
```

but it doesn't work, it always going into the if nomather how big the $money is

Comment: Why do you bother making an array when you only check the first element of that array?

Comment: @Sherif what should I do ?

Comment: I don't know. What do you intend to have happen here?

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($array[0]);` or `Log::info($array[0]);` ?

Comment: @Sherif i want to check, if money bigger then amount, then show and save (amount - money)

Comment: Did you read the doc's on Laravel's `::select()`? Does it *return* json? `json_decode`

Comment: @GetSet They're encoding then decoding to get an associative array. Which of course then means that `$value->amount` won't work since it's an array, not an object.

Comment: @aynber ahh I see now.

Comment: This has a SQL injection in it which is completely unnecessary in Laravel. As a general rule, **DO NOT** put things like `$user` inside of queries. Always use placeholder values for data, or the Laravel scoping facilities that aynber demonstrates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd be better off changing the query so you only get the value of the user you're looking for.

```
$amount = DB::table('user_check')->where('user_id', $user)->pluck('amount');
```

or if amount is an array instead of a single value (version dependent)

```
$amount = DB::table('user_check')->where('user_id', $user)->value('amount');
```

OR

```
$user = DB::table('user_check')->where('user_id', $user)->first();
$amount = $user ? $user->amount : 0;
```

Comment: Won't `pluck()` return an array? As I remember - it was `->value('columnName')` to get a single value from a single row.

Comment: I was trying to remember the difference between versions. I have 4.2, where pluck returns a single value.

Comment: I think they renamed `pluck` to `value` and `lists` to `pluck`. V4.x is quite old :-)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Hah, don't I know it. Upgrading is on my to-do list. I've updated the answer with another way to go about it.

Comment: See the differences: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries and https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries. It's `pluck` in 4.2 and `value` in 5.8

Answer (score 0):

> (int) will return 0 if the value is "false", "null", or "0". And i bet you don't want to have that query to search for a user with ID of 0 in case the request input is not set or malformed.

## Let us clean that code:

```php
$userId = request()->get('user');
$money = (int) request()->get('money'); 
# (int) here will be 0 if the request('money') is not sent with the request
# so it makes sense to have it here.

$userCheck = DB::table('user_check')->select('amount')
            ->where('user_id', $userId)
            ->first();

# ->first(); if you want to return a single row item
# ->get(); if you want to return multiple items, this one will return a collection (array) 
# and you need to treat that accordingly using foreach, or any array function
```

> Why do you need `$array = json_decode(json_encode($data), True);` ?

```php
if($userCheck->amount > $money){
    return response(['user ok'=> $userCheck,'money'=>$money]);
}else{
    return response('user not ok');
}
```

Now i assume you're using the (int) to get the integer value of sent data, there's no actual need there, and in case of validation you need to validate that separately like so:

### If it's in controller

```php
$this->validate($request,[
    'user'=>'required|exists:user_check,id',
    'money'=>'integer'
]);
```

### If you want to make the validation elsewhere you can:

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'user'=>'required|exists:user_check,id',
    'money'=>'integer'
]);

# Check if it fails
if($validator->fails()){
   # Validator fails, stop and return the errors instead
   return response()->with($validator->getMessageBag());
}

# This will validate the request and make sure that it has 'user'
# And that 'user' exists in the `user_check` table with that ID
# and that 'money' is an integer
```

> If you're willing to validate you can put that code above the `DB::table()...`

I hope that solves your problem, let me know how it goes.